# Is there another way to center an element in the middle of the page

Tags: css

I know that we normally use `margin:auto` however I am using the code below.

**HTML :**

```
<article>
  <header></header>
</article>
```

**CSS:**

```
article{
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto; /* goes in the middle - great */
}
header{
  width: 130%;
  margin-left: -30%;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VG8P5/)

At this point I am placing the `article` in the center. However, as the browser/window size gets smaller, I would like to center the article as if its width was as wide as the `header`. Basically, at some point (as you shrink the browser window) the `header` will be at the edge on the left, whilst not taking advantage of the blank space on the right.

I don't want to have an extra `div`, but if I did, I would wrap the article in a `div` and give it an auto margin.

[screenshot http://i3.minus.com/i2yPFqNDgeBbS.png](http://i3.minus.com/i2yPFqNDgeBbS.png)

Comment: `width: 130%`? Why is that?

Comment: to get the effect you see on the example, to get the header be 30% wider then the article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but don't you just want:

```
margin-left: 15%;
```

on the header?

Comment: that would move the header but not the article as well

Comment: Can you show us exactly what you want in the (not so good) case? You want the relative relationship between red and blue the same, but then with blue centered? In the (good) case, red is centered, so when do you want to switch from red-centered to blue-centered?

Comment: On the not so good case you can see a gap on the right (where I put the cross) and no gap on the left. For example, at the moment I used few media query breakpoints and added some left margin to the header AND the article.

Comment: Really my question was whether there was a way to automatically do this, It wasn't whether there is a work around. I was more interested whether css was capable of centring the article as if it was as wide as the header. As of course there are so many work arounds (so all the answers as "work arounds" are correct

Comment: I still don't understand what kind of behaviour you want in the "narrow" window case - can you post a picture of what the desired behaviour would be?

Comment: What I wanted to know is whether it can be don without an extra div. However, this http://jsfiddle.net/VG8P5/10/ demonstrates what I need but without that wrapping div. So Is there a way to center the article as if it was `390px` wide even though it is '300px'

Comment: OK, I understand what you mean now. Can't think of how you would achieve it without the extra DIV though.

Comment: Non of the answers give me what I need - maybe because it can not be done. I ended up using `margin-left: 15%;` and madie queries to get the effect without having to use extra divs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This code does what is described, but if you want to keep the two edges aligned you would need to get into some javascript, I recommend jquery for this kind of thing.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .header {
                width: 960px;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                position: relative;
                left: -100px;

                background-color: blue;
            }
            .article {
                width: 75%;
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;

                background-color: blue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">Header</div>
        <div class="article">TODO write content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```